# How to handle this copy issue?

Tags: discussion

I was informed by [Prince](https://health.stackexchange.com/users/6972/prince) that a copy of [my question](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/7229/what-is-the-effect-of-soap-on-a-blister?noredirect=1#comment14816_7229) was put on the site [www.sciencerr.com](http://www.sciencerr.com/question/what-is-the-effect-of-soap-on-a-blister/). I dit not do this and I do not have an account on this website (as suggerated by [them](http://www.sciencerr.com/view-profile/?profile=Karlo)).

It seems that more questions have been copied to [the site](http://www.sciencerr.com/). Is this a legitimite act?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've reported this site to Stack Exchange as a scraper that is copying our content without attribution. If you ever see another site doing something like this, you can report it at our [contact page](https://health.stackexchange.com/contact) or follow the instructions on [this Meta SE post.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200177/a-site-or-scraper-is-copying-content-from-stack-exchange-what-do-i-do)